# Let $X_{n}$, $n \geq 0$, be the two-state Markov chain. Find

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

a) $P_0(T_0=n)$

b) $P_0(T_1=n)$

> In class my we were learning about hitting times. $$T_a; \text{stands for the first time we hit state}\ \textit{"a"} \\\\
> T_a=min\{n\ |n>0\ \text{and} \ X_n=a\}$$ My professor defined $$P_0(T_0=n)=P(T_0=n|X_0=0)$$ where we
>   as hitting state zero in n-steps, $n\geq 0$.  For a 2-state Markov chain we know, $$P(0,0)=1-p\
> > \ \ P(0,1)=p\ \ \ P(1,1)=1-q\ \ \ P(1,0)=q$$ so I let n=4 and found
>   each probability to see if there was a pattern that I could show for
>   the general case, but I think this approach is wrong. I would like
>   help and/or hints with both parts, if that's not to much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

there are two states, 0 and 1. you start at 0 and don't end up there again until move $n$. From markovianity, the answer is
$$
\pi(0) \cdot  P(0,1) \cdot  \underbrace{  P(1,1)  \cdots P(1,1)}_{n-2}  \cdot P(1,0)
$$